# How can I create braces around aligned equations?

Tags: best-practices

What appears on my page is how I want it to look, but please advise on how I can do this with better code. I have `\addtolength{\jot}{0.3ex}` in the preamble.

```
\begin{flalign*}
      L&= \left(u^S\right)^{0.5}\left(u^T\right)^{0.5} - \lambda \left(u^S+u^T-9.9\right)\\[1ex]
\smash{\raisebox{-1.4\baselineskip}{$\left\{\rule{0cm}{1.5cm}\right.$}}
0=\dfrac{\textrm d L}{\textrm d u^S}&= 0.5\left(u^S\right)^{-0.5}\left(u^T\right)^{0.5}-\lambda \tag{1} \\
\implies\ \ \ 0=\dfrac{\textrm d L}{\textrm d u^T}&= \left(u^S\right)^{0.5}0.5\left(u^T\right)^{-0.5}-\lambda \tag{2} \\
u^S + u^T &= 9.9 \tag{3}
&\end{flalign*}
```

[image]

Comment: Google: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Braces_spanning_multiple_lines

Comment: since you want the separate lines numbered, take a look at the `\empheq` package.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes, but with that you don't get an alignment across all 4 rows on the equal sign I think

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something has to give here unfortunately as `amsmath` doesn't support that kind of partial vertical+horizontal alignment out of the box, but only with some manual gymnastics. So on the whole I would do something similar to you, i.e. stick mainly with a basic alignment environent of `amsmath`, especially if you really try to align all four rows on the equation signs.

What I would do differently is a) move the large lbrace into a macro definition like this:

```
\newcommand\smashedlbrace[2][0]{\ 
   \smash{\raisebox{#1\baselineskip}%
                   {\mathsurround 0pt     % <- extra
                    $\left\{\rule{0cm}{#2cm}\right.$}}\ }
```

and make use of the fact that you have 3 equations to overlay, thus it is best placed after the `\implies` because then there is no need to raise or lower anything :-) but I made provisions for that via the optional argument.

b) Add some \phantom into the last equation to open it up matching the others

c) your extended \jot is matter of taste ... I like it as the whole thing otherwise looks quite cramped

d) probably a good idea to use a def like \dd as well to make things more readable; or even better use the `esdiff` package as @Bernard in his anser suggested

That gives us

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\dd{\mathrm{d}}

\newcommand\smashedlbrace[2][0]{\ 
  \smash{\raisebox{#1\baselineskip}%
                  {\mathsurround 0pt     % <- extra for safety
                    $\left\{\rule{0cm}{#2cm}\right.$}}\ }

\begin{document}

\addtolength{\jot}{0.5ex}

\begin{flalign*}
     L&= \left(u^S\right)^{0.5}\left(u^T\right)^{0.5} - \lambda \left(u^S+u^T-9.9\right)\\
0=\dfrac{\textrm d L}{\dd u^S}&= 0.5\left(u^S\right)^{-0.5}\left(u^T\right)^{0.5}-\lambda \tag{1} \\
\implies
\smashedlbrace{1.3} 
   0=\dfrac{\dd L}{\dd u^T}&= \left(u^S\right)^{0.5}0.5\left(u^T\right)^{-0.5}-\lambda \tag{2} \\
u^S + u^T &= 9.9 \tag{3}
\phantom{\dfrac{L}{u^T}}         % to open up last equation
&\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

and compiled

[image]

Comment: I have an improvement, which lets your command be used for an even number of lines: `{\mathsurround 0pt    $\implies \left\{\rule{0cm}{#2cm}\right.$}}\ }`

Comment: @ahorn yes that is probably better, but then you may want to go all the way and add the "\implies" as a parameter value so that you can  add something in front of it with ease.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution based a `empheq` and `esdiff`, a package which greatly simplifies typing (partial) derivatives. Needless to load `amsmath` since `empheq loads`mathtools , which loads `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq, esdiff}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{3ex}
$ L= \left(u^S\right)^{0.5}\left(u^T\right)^{0.5} - \lambda\left(u^S+u^T-9.9\right)$\vspace{1ex}
\begin{empheq}[left=\implies\empheqlbrace]{flalign}
  &0=\diff{L}{u^S}= 0.5\left(u^S\right)^{-0.5}\left(u^T\right)^{0.5}-\lambda , & \\
  &0=\diff{ L}{u^T}= \left(u^S\right)^{0.5}0.5\left(u^T\right)^{-0.5}-\lambda,\\
  & u^S + u^T = 9.9.
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like that but how can you get the alignment on the = sign for all four lines as well?

Comment: @ahorn: Sorry for the `λ`. My editor is configured so that it displays the Greek letter (I have a shortcut for that), but saves it as the usual `\lambda`, so it can compile. I've fixed the code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to align all four lines but want the brace only to cover the last three lines, you can use an overlay with a tikz drawing. The command

```
\tikzcoord[optional vertical shift]{label}
```

defined as

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\tikzcoord[2][0ex]%
  {\raisebox{#1}{\tikz[remember picture]\coordinate(#2);}}
```

labels a point in the equations for later reference in the tikz picture. The brace can be drawn using

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
...
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] ...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\dd{\mathrm{d}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\newcommand\tikzcoord[2][0ex]{\raisebox{#1}{\tikz[remember picture]\coordinate(#2);}}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
  L & = \left(u^S\right)^{0.5}\left(u^T\right)^{0.5} - \lambda \left(u^S+u^T-9.9\right)\\[1ex]
  \tikzcoord[2.2ex]{a}\;\;
  0=\dfrac{\dd L}{\dd u^S}
    & = 0.5\left(u^S\right)^{-0.5}\left(u^T\right)^{0.5}-\lambda \tag{1} \\
  0=\dfrac{\dd L}{\dd u^T}
    & = \left(u^S\right)^{0.5}0.5\left(u^T\right)^{-0.5}-\lambda \tag{2} \\
  \tikzcoord[-0.5ex]{b}
  u^S + u^T 
    & = 9.9 \tag{3}
\end{flalign*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror},thick] (a) --node[left]{$\Rightarrow\;$} (a|-b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```